# Is this a good example of delayed evaluation and backtracking before is/2 in prolog?

Tags: prolog

The following query in prolog succeeds.

```
?- X=3, Y is X+2.

X = 3,
Y = 5
```

In contrast, the following results in prolog throwing an error (not even failing in the usual sense to allow backtracking).

```
?- Y is X+2,  X=3.

Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated
```

We know this is because numerical calculations in prolog are "unprolog-like".

The following example appears to allow prolog to apply its ability to do backtracking and search, and delay actual evaluation.

```
?- Y=X+2, X=3, Z is Y.

X = 3,
Y = 3+2,
Z = 5
```

I am not an expert in prolog so my **questions** are:

1. Is there a proper name for this pattern? Is it called 'delayed evaluation'.
2. Will the same pattern actually allow backtracking in the first part (in a more sophisticated example than this) for multiple solutions to be 'evaluated' by the is/2 infix operator?

Comment: This works only for very simple expressions. Rather consider constraints.

Comment: yes, this will allow backtracking, e.g. in `Y=X+2, member(X,[1,2,3]), Y is 4.` As for the name, maybe it's "failure-driven backtracking", but then, all backtracking is driven by failure, so I don't really know what to call it. you must be really careful with this approach though, you have to make sure that everything is ready for `is` so it does not cause an error.

Comment: I don't think it is delayed evaluation because the evaluation happens when you tell it to happen, you just tell it to happen later by calling `is` later. `is` evaluates Prolog terms that double as arithmetic expressions into answers, but `Y=X+2` is not *necessarily* arithmetic. It is a two-argument term with a name shared with addition symbol `Y=+(X,2)` like `Y=cat(dog,2)`. You could do things other than evaluate it arithmetically, e.g. `_+Num = Y` to get `Num=2`, or `functor(Y, Name, _)` to get `Name=+`. (Compare Python where you cannot write y=x+2 without meaning add now).

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your method is that Y holds the calculation `X+2` rather than the value `5`, so another variable `Z` is needed to hold the calculated value `5`, and you have to add the line `Z is Y` when you're *confident* that X has a value.

Instead, can use [freeze](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=freeze/2), to automatically calculate Y *as soon as* X has a value:

```
?- freeze(X, Y is X + 2), X = 3.
X = 3,
Y = 5.
```

For such a simple situation, `freeze` is sufficient.

For more complex situations, use [clpfd](https://github.com/triska/clpfd) (for integers & Booleans), or e.g. [clpBNR](https://github.com/ridgeworks/clpBNR) (which can also handle reals, i.e. floating-point numbers).

Comment: Counterexample: `?- freeze(X, Y is X + 2), X = 1+Z.` If at all use `when(ground(Expr),Y is Expr).`

Comment: You now have two people telling you that the OP needs to use constraints. You really should remove this answer and post an answer that uses constraints. Or risk getting a down vote. My personal favorite examples for this is to convert Fahrenheit to Celsius and vis-a-versa. Also leave one of the values undefined and show what happens. Don't forget to show how freeze resides under the covers of constraints.